# Prevent access or disable some function in a certain page when some user already accessing

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I want to disable some function like hide submit button to a certain page when a remote user is currently accessing it, to prevent duplication of work.My idea to create a helper but I have no idea how to implement it

```
 <?php

     function isLock() {
          //disable submit button if a user currently accessing it
      }

      function unLock() {
          //re enable submit button if no user is accessing it
     }
```

A Javascript solution is also welcome

Comment: maintain flag in database for the user, and according to that flag implement the code

Comment: can you give me some hint on it?

Answer (score 0):

Let say there is one table that keeps track of users accessing pages.

**table_access**

```
userid pageid current_access
  1      1      Yes
  1      2      No
  2      2      No
  3      3      No
```

`Now check that if the user is accessing the page or not. If it returns yes then disable submit button otherwise keep it enable.`

**Query:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_access WHERE userid = 1 AND pageid = 1 AND current_access = 'Yes'";
```

if above query returns records >0 then disable the submit button.

**EDIT:**

Update table_access whenever user lands on that page.